# How can I post Audio using facebook SDK with android

Tags: android, facebook

How can I post Audio using facebook SDK with android ? instead of uploading them to a third party server and share the link. Or use a third party app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there is currently a way to do this. You'll have to upload it to a 3rd party service such as [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/) and then post a link. If the 3rd party service supports embedding in Facebook (and SoundCloud does), then your users will be able to listen to the audio right on their news feed.

Another option might be to use ["feed gaming"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/) -

> Developers can leverage in-feed gaming to create engaging stories for
>   users. This involves publishing a story on behalf of a user which has
>   a flash object attached. When a user's friends see these attachments,
>   they will be able to click to play them inline. This opens up some
>   interesting scenarios for a small embeddable version of your game to
>   be shown to a user's friends, at the end of which you can encourage
>   them to click through to your canvas app.

This method is meant for gaming but if you develop your own audio player, you'll be able to let your users upload the audio file to your servers and them stream them though the inline swf.